How to auto-link issue IDs to an external issue tracker in Azure Repos?
I use Azure Repos and an external issue tracker. My commits start with AB-123. I want those IDs to be linked to my external issue tracker like to http://myissue-tracker/AB-123.
How to do this in Azure Repos? I guess it is possible with Github but I want it in Azure Repos.
